# Transparent background with compositing not working

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, shader-nodes

*I'm new in blender, thanks for the patience.*

### Abstract:

I have this simple **volume shader** I applied into this **object** (**Images below**), and I want to **make** a simple **white colored background** with composer.

[image]

[image: Shader]
(Shader)

[image: The white box is a primitive example object]
(Render without compositor)

### The problem:

The **only way I know** how to make it is by using the **alpha over + RGB** nodes (**Image below**), but the **shader objects get overwritten** by the color. I think it's because the **shader** doesn't have **any surface node** connected.

[image: Pink BG overwrite the shader]
(Render with compositor)

### Solution?:

Is there another way to make it? Do i need to understand something to work propely?

Comment: if you're talking about your 3 objects on the right, it looks like they haven't been rendered, are you sure that they are visible for render?

Comment: Yep they are, i've checked the "Disabled in renders" box and did a render text without the compositor, everything normal. Thanks for the response.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I did it now :D

Comment: maybe read this page: https://developer.blender.org/T65993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of the three solutions are described by 'L0Lock', thanks for your effort.

### Abstract

The issue here is that Blender doesn't consider a volume with a density of zero can possibly affect the alpha as it's a volume that doesn't "exist".

### Solution 1

So one way to fix that is to adapt your *Principled Volume* shader with some density that can be rendered:

[image: demo shader fix]

Here I just set the density to 1 and plugged your color ramp into the *Principled Volume*'s color.

### Solution 2

Alternatively, you can keep your shader, but instead of using the alpha pass for the Alpha Over's factor, you just use the beauty pass (the full combined "image"output from the render layer node) which has its own straight alpha. It's not ideal, but it works by simply leaving the factor input empty:

[image: demo straight alpha]

### Solution 3

This one thanks to 'Game Abuse Studio' found here:

https://youtu.be/tmb5HRU1cUo

Actually this one worked better in my case. The basic here is that is a png render, and I added a background in post production.

**Disclaimer:**
If you're a beginner like myself that don't know how to use the video editing and all the render properties, I can't solve one issue.
When you group the image sequence and render, the transparency vanishes. But when I grouped in another software like Davinci Resolve worked very fine.

Comment: Solution 3 a bit far-fetched - and technically incorrect in terms of color preservation. Besides, it's literally answering the topic "Transparent background with compositing not working" by "don't use transparency". If you just need to put whatever color you want in the background, a sturdier and "correct" solution could be to set the color in your world shader.